# Loops in Unix script

Tags: loops, unix

Currently, I have written my script in the following manner:

```
c3d COVMap.nii -thresh 10 Inf 1 0 -o thresh_cov_beyens_plus10.nii
c3d COVMap.nii -thresh 9.7436 Inf 1 0 -o thresh_cov_beyens_plus97436.nii
c3d COVMap.nii -thresh 9.4872 Inf 1 0 -o thresh_cov_beyens_plus94872.nii
c3d COVMap.nii -thresh 9.2308 Inf 1 0 -o thresh_cov_beyens_plus92308.nii
c3d COVMap.nii -thresh 8.9744 Inf 1 0 -o thresh_cov_beyens_plus89744.nii
c3d COVMap.nii -thresh 8.7179 Inf 1 0 -o thresh_cov_beyens_plus87179.nii
c3d COVMap.nii -thresh 8.4615 Inf 1 0 -o thresh_cov_beyens_plus84615.nii
c3d COVMap.nii -thresh 8.2051 Inf 1 0 -o thresh_cov_beyens_plus82051.nii
c3d COVMap.nii -thresh 7.9487 Inf 1 0 -o thresh_cov_beyens_plus79487.nii
c3d COVMap.nii -thresh 7.6923 Inf 1 0 -o thresh_cov_beyens_plus76923.nii
c3d COVMap.nii -thresh 7.4359 Inf 1 0 -o thresh_cov_beyens_plus74359.nii
c3d COVMap.nii -thresh 7.1795 Inf 1 0 -o thresh_cov_beyens_plus71795.nii
c3d COVMap.nii -thresh 6.9231 Inf 1 0 -o thresh_cov_beyens_plus69231.nii
```

But I want the values in the form of some array like `x=[10,9.7436,9.4872...,6.9231]`

And I want the script to be called as follows:

```
x=[10,9.7436,9.4872...,6.9231]
c3d COVMap.nii -thresh x[0] Inf 1 0 -o thresh_cov_beyens_plus10.nii
c3d COVMap.nii -thresh x[1] Inf 1 0 -o thresh_cov_beyens_plus97436.nii
c3d COVMap.nii -thresh x[2] Inf 1 0 -o thresh_cov_beyens_plus94872.nii
c3d COVMap.nii -thresh x[3] Inf 1 0 -o thresh_cov_beyens_plus92308.nii
...
c3d COVMap.nii -thresh x[14] Inf 1 0 -o thresh_cov_beyens_plus87179.nii
```

Could someone please suggest a method to loop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use bash, you can do arrays

```
arr=(10 9.7436 9.4872 ... 6.9231)

for x in ${arr[@]}; do
    c3d COVMap.nii -thresh $x Inf 1 0 -o thresh_cov_beyens_plus${x/./}.nii
done
```

Just make sure the elements in the array are separated by a space instead of comma and use parentheses instead of square bracket. The `${arr[@]}` will expand as the elements of the array separated by a space. The `${x/./}` will remove the decimal point from the element to make the filename suffix.

You could actually do it without an array at all by just putting the values separated by spaced in place of the `${arr[#]}`.

```
for x in 10 9.7436 9.4872 ... 6.9231; do
    c3d COVMap.nii -thresh $x Inf 1 0 -o thresh_cov_beyens_plus${x/./}.nii
done
```

or perhaps a little cleaner by using a normal variable

```
values="10 9.7436 9.4872 ... 6.9231"

for x in $values; do
    c3d COVMap.nii -thresh $x Inf 1 0 -o thresh_cov_beyens_plus${x/./}.nii
done
```

This works because expanding `$values` without surrounding quotes (ie `"$values"`) will cause BASH to parse each word inside of the variable. So it's effectively the same as the previous code example.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to try this now :) Thank you very much!